# Dynamic Variables in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Ideal state, show a calculation of field "@ytd_savings_per_participant" divided by 3 as %%=v(@Lattes)=%% within a dynamic message. The message is based as well on the field "@ytd_savings_per_participant". If the value is under 300 in "@ytd_savings_per_participant" I'd like it to say

"That could buy %%=v(@Lattes)=%% number of Lattes"

I cannot get the variable to populate here. I can get it to pull in outside of the dynamic field but now within. Code below as well as screenshot attached to show the two places I put the %%=v(@Lattes)=%% field.[image: Screen shot of preview and test]

```
var @YTDS, @message, @ytd_savings_per_participant, @num2, @Lattes

Set @ytd_savings_per_participant = ytd_savings_per_participant

Set @YTDS = FormatNumber(@ytd_savings_per_participant, "C")

Set @num2 = 3
Set @Lattes = Divide(@ytd_savings_per_participant, @num2)

]%%

%%[if @ytd_savings_per_participant <=299 then
  set @message = "With those savings you could buy %%=v(@Lattes)=%% latt&eacute;s"


elseif @ytd_savings_per_participant >=300 AND @ytd_savings_per_participant <=1000 THEN
 set @message = "With those savings you could buy a new flatscreen"

elseif @ytd_savings_per_participant >=1000 AND @ytd_savings_per_participant <=1999 then
 set @message = "With those savings you could buy a new sofa"
 
 elseif @ytd_savings_per_participant >=2000 AND @ytd_savings_per_participant <=3000 then
  set @message = "With those savings you could buy a family vacation"

ENDIF
]%%
<center>
 <br>
  &nbsp;<div align="center">
  <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; line-height: 23px;">Dollars Saved Lattes:%%=v(@Lattes)=%%</span> </div><br>
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="background: #ffffff; color: #17A062; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; line-height: 28px; padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;">%%=v(@YTDS)=%%
        
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <div align="center">

    <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; line-height: 23px;">
    <br>%%=v(@message)=%%&sup1;
    </span>
    <br><br>
  <span style="font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px;">
    Get an estimate of your other savings<br> with our calculator.
</span>
    <br><br>
  
      
    </div>
  
</center>
```

In the above code you can see I put the value %%v(@Lattes)=%% in 2 places to test if it would work. It only pulls in when outside of the variable message

Comment: try to concat this:
set @ message = concat("With those savings you could buy ", @ Lattes , " latt&eacute;s")

Comment: Thanks @EazyE that worked!!

Comment: I moved my comment to answer, go ahead and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

From comment:

You should use concact on this line

`set @message = "With those savings you could buy %%=v(@Lattes)=%% latt&eacute;s"`

to

`set @message = concat("With those savings you could buy ", @Lattes , " latt&eacute;s")`